# Unable to access jsp file in JBoss 7

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

I put a JSP file in my application. But I receive 404 error: "HTTP Status 404 - Could not find resource for relative : /ping.jsp of full path: http://localhost:8080/asset/ping.jsp".

Following is the source code of the JSP file:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

When I request the page using http://localhost:8080/asset/ping.jsp URL, I get following log messages in server.log:

```
17:12:06,160 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies]  (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=48YjapAO5bg5Yxt8XqRlDucr; org.cups.sid=264b18fffb2ee21f51a099617839d14f
17:12:06,177 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory]  (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Found BeanManager at java:comp/BeanManager
17:12:06,181 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment]  (http--0.0.0.0-8080-1) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.passo.framework.remote.servlet.CachedServices$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
```

Comment: Follow below answer, you should revise the question's title.

Comment: What kind of revision does the title need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that, my rest application class was bound to "/"

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class CachedServices extends Application {


}
```

After I updated the `ApplicationContextPath` to a different path, I was able to access JSP files.

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/cached")
public class CachedServices extends Application {


}
```